# Is it possible to share rpc endpoint for azure blockchain service with restricted access?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, geth, quorum, azure-blockchain-service

I want to create ERC20 token on azure blockchain service, and want to allow publicly sending ERC20 tokens and checking balances using metamask. However, I want to allow only sending ERC20 tokens, but don't want to allow other administrative operations publicly.
Is it possible to share rpc with such a restricted access right?

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one rpc port and every client connecting to this rpc will have the same right.

You can use IPC to do your administrative operation.